# how to solve scrolling BackDropFilter low FPS on Android

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to get a frosted glass effect on top of a widget and i used a `BackdropFilter` and the desired effect was met. but then i figured out that made my app so laggy especially when scrolling the widget that had the filter effect on top.

here is my BackdropFilter sample :

```
ClipRect(
                child: BackdropFilter(
                  filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: blurPower!=null?blurPower.key:2, sigmaY: blurPower!=null?blurPower.value:3),
                  child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: blurColor??Colors.grey.shade100.withOpacity(0.2),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(borderRadius??Radius.circular(10)),
                        border: Border.all(width: .3, color: MyTheme.bgBottomBar),
                      )
                  ),
                ),
              )
```

without the BackdropFilter my FPS is around 32fps but with it on it gets to 7fps on average and that is unacceptable.

my question is a way to mitigate the fps drop or a way to get the same effect in an other way.

Comment: you're measuring  FPS on release mode right?

Comment: your code is not enough to remake the problem your experiencing

Comment: @easazade yes, on the profile mode to be precise. For the code, i don't really know what can i give more for it to be more understandable, that Cliprect is the cause of the slowdown, and omitting it makes the fps go higher. It is part of a `Stack` which is the child of a `container` that is present inside a `CustomScrollView`.